# Create Frame from Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter, window, frame

my program currently is used as a gym tracker and so has a frame which displays a users routine. However at the minute I have only got one routine and so to be able to create multiple routines I need a button which creates a frame for a new routine. To do this I have a button on the first frame which links to a command which should create the new frame, however it is returning an error. This is the code:

```
 def AddRoutine(self, window):

    self.window = window
    window.state("zoomed")
    self.window.title('Routine')
    window.update_idletasks()

    h = self.window.winfo_height()
    w = self.window.winfo_width()
    Center_h = h/2
    Center_w = w/2

    self.newFr = Frame(window, bg = "PaleTurquoise1")
    self.RFrame.append(self.newFr)
    self.newFr.place(x = Center_w , y = Center_h, anchor = "center", width = 1024, height = 800)
```

I currently have a list `RFrame` which is added to every time a new frame is created, this is so the program knows how many frames their are.

When I run the code the error is `TypeError: AddRoutine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'` however I do not know how this error is coming up.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the argument when you invoke the function

Comment: Surely `self.window = window` is the parameter ?

Comment: When you call the function

Comment: `self.btn_Add = Button(self.FrameRoutine, text = "Add Routine", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial", "16"), command = self.AddRoutine,  width = 20)
                                                                                          self.btn_Add.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)`

Comment: However if I include window then it calls the function without pressing the button.

Comment: command = lambda:self.AddRoutine(window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
command = lambda:self.AddRoutine(window)
```

To call function with arguments for tkinter Button